# Is converting to the uniqueidentifier datatype static?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working in SQL Server 2012. I am trying to "calculate" a unique number from a username in order to mask the username from others in a query. I have discovered the *uniqueidentifier* datatype and was wondering if this is something that remains static for each run of a query, even on different machines.

For example, if we have a username of **xyz**, I am doing some string manipulations to jumble the username up in a way that keeps it distinct from others, then converting it to *varbinary*: **0x78797A**. However, this can obviously vary in length depending on the length of the username. I don't want the users to be able to see a long *varbinary* set and assume (probably correctly) that it's the person with the longest username.

I then converted this *varbinary* into *uniqueidentifier* datatype. After running this several times, it would appear as though this new value will remain static, but I'm not sure if this is because I am running it on the same machine. I would need this to be static no matter when it is run or where. Is it possible that *uniqueidentifier* could result in a different value with the same input in any circumstance?

Comment: Converting a varbinary to uniqueidentifier is deterministic.

But this doesn't seem to be a useful approach.

How are you dealing with names longer than 16 characters? How are you padding out the varbinary to 16 bytes if shorter? The zeros will still show the length. http://rextester.com/NFTDHM25938

Comment: @MartinSmith, thanks for the information of it being deterministic! You're right that this isn't the most useful approach, but I don't have permissions to some of the feature of SQL Server that would allow some other type of encryption. For my purposes, the 16 character limits will not be an issue and the zeros showing the length is _much_ less correlated that I thought it would be. I appreciate the feedback!

Comment: Note that any hashing function (even one with a length like SHA2_512) has a possibility of collision

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the SQL Hash function.  It will stay static when given the same input.  MD2 is the name of the algorithm I am using in this example, but you can choose others.

MD2, MD4, MD5 any of these will be 16 characters

SHA, SHA1 either of these will be 20 characters

SHA2_256 will be 32 characters

SHA2_512 will be 64 characters

```
DECLARE @UserName VARCHAR(25) = 'xyz'
SELECT
     @UserName UserName
    ,HASHBYTES('MD2',@UserName) UserNameHash
    ,LEN(HASHBYTES('MD2',@UserName)) CharLength
```

MSDN Article on Hashbytes:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415.aspx

Comment: This is a neat idea that's also pretty simple, but it sounds like SeanC has a point about it not necessarily being distinct. I had a similar idea of seeding a random number with the username, but figured that there was still the probability that the identifier would not be distinct. A _very_ small probability if I generated enough numbers, but still... Anyway, thanks for the insight!

Comment: If you want a truly distinct values you would add a uniqueidentifier column and populate it with `SELECT NEWID()`.  However, this is not calculated, it is a one time distinct value given by SQL. Also the odds of a collision for SHA or SHA1 is more than 1 in 1*10^18. [hash-collision-probabilities](http://preshing.com/20110504/hash-collision-probabilities/).  I was curious so I looked it up.

Comment: Yeah I assumed the probability is extremely low, so that's interesting. Of course, I will never win the lottery, but I will assign the same ID to different users if there is even a chance of it. :)